# Write results of google to html pages

Tags: bash, shell, web-scraping, web-crawler, wget

I want to download randomly many Excel files (eg, .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm) from Internet.

In the first place, I "google" files having `.xlsx` as postfix. I have the following shell:

```
for  (( i=0 ; i<400 ; i=i+10 )) ; do
    wget -O $i.html "https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=filetype:xlsx&start=$i"
done
```

The above shell generates `0.html`, `10.html`... Oddly, all the generated pages are the same:

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential of `wget` in this connection is a bit limited, you could try to use, e.g.,

```
lynx -dump "http://google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=filetype:xlsx&start=$i" > output
```

However, one should keep the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/policies/terms/) in mind, especially:

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.

Comment: I see `...` in address extracted, e.g., `www.phoutcomes.info/.../PHOF_inequalities_data_available_May_2015.xlsx`. How to avoid this?

Comment: what was the query string? In general, `lynx` returns a formatted "list", where each link is assigned a number, list of full links can be found at the end of the page

Comment: `lynx -dump "http://google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=filetype:xlsx&start=30" > 30.html`

Comment: see the list at the end of the page, item 34 - so that you could `grep` for `url?q=` and extract the links